# Display cuts types in scipampl

Tags: ampl, scip

I use scipampl as the MILP solver in AMPL. I would like to find out what cuts are generated. While scipampl shows the number of cuts during the solving process, it does not show the kinds of cuts. To find out the cuts, the only way I know is to open up the interactive shell for scip and display statistics after solving. But this method is not working for me when I need to solve many problems in AMPL and collect data after the runs.

I am wondering if there is a way to ask scipampl to print out information for cuts (or other information such as LP calls) without launching the interactive shell.

Another related question is how to display partial statistics. Rather than showing everything, is there a command like "display statistics cuts".

I looked into options in "scip.set", but display options do not seem offer what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the option
  display/statistics = TRUE
in a SCIP settings file, you should get the complete statistics.
(This option doesn't come from SCIP itself, but is added by the AMPL interface.)

As far as I know, there is nothing to limit the statistics to separators only.

Comment: Scipampl issues warning "WARNING: unknown parameter <display/statistics>". I use AMPL Version 20141206 and SCIP version 3.0.1. What do I miss here? Thanks!

Comment: The parameter display/statistics is available since SCIP 3.1, so you should update your SCIP installation.